# 'Unexpected end of input block in comment' exception thrown when synapse configuration block is commented

Tags: wso2-integration-studio

`'com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected end of input block in comment'` exception thrown when a configuration block is commented out in synapse.

Looks like the XML is not being parsed when an XML is commented out. If I have give a general XML as `<!-- test -->`, it gets parsed without any error.

Is there any workaround or a solution to overcome this issue?

Synapse Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="HelloWorld1" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"Hello":"World"}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <sequence description="dfs" key="abcSequence"/>
            <!-- <sequence key="testIn"/> -->
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Error Log:

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected end of input block in comment
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,29]
    at com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException.throwLazily(WstxLazyException.java:45)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:720)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:858)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.createComment(StAXOMBuilder.java:474)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:279)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(AXIOMUtil.java:54)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(AXIOMUtil.java:39)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.deserializer.DummyMediatorFactoryFinder.getFactory(DummyMediatorFactoryFinder.java:241)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.validator.ProcessSourceView.validate(ProcessSourceView.java:954)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.validator.ProcessSourceView.mediatorValidation(ProcessSourceView.java:860)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.validator.ProcessSourceView.synapseValidation(ProcessSourceView.java:779)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.validator.ProcessSourceView.validateSynapseContent(ProcessSourceView.java:145)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.doSave(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.lambda$0(SaveableHelper.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.lambda$3(SaveableHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:278)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a validation error in Integration Studio 6.5.0. (and in WSO2 EI Tooling 6.4.0) We have fixed it for the upcoming release. Please refer https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/3985 for more details.